# No metric on $\mathbb R^{\infty}$ whose projections are the absolute-value metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\mathbb R^{\infty}$ be the space of all real sequences. I have the following conjecture: There is no metric on this space such that if two sequences differ in only one coordinate, then the distance between them is the absolute value of the difference between the respective coordinate values. More formally:

> There exists no metric $\rho:\mathbb R^{\infty}\times\mathbb R^{\infty}\to[0,\infty)$ with the following property: if $\mathbf x,\mathbf y\in\mathbb R^{\infty}$ are such that there exists an $i\in\mathbb N$ such that $x_j=y_j$ for every $j\in\mathbb N\setminus\{i\}$, then $$\rho(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)=|x_i-y_i|.$$

For example, such a metric would yield $\rho((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\ldots),(1,2,12,4,5,6,7,\ldots))=9$.

I tried showing that such a candidate metric would necessarily violate the triangle inequality, or it would yield infinite values, but to no avail. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: If you had such a metric, then couldn't you use induction and triangle inequality to show that $\rho(0,(1,1,1,\dotsc))$ is greater than $n$ for every $n$?

Comment: @ziggurism I did try precisely this, but I am stuck finding the right chain of triangle inequalities doing the trick.

Comment: @ziggurism Also, if one restricts attention to the space of _bounded_ real sequences $\ell^{\infty}$, then the sup metric clearly satisfies the condition indicated in my conjecture and the distance between $(0,0,\ldots)$ and $(1,1,\ldots)$ is finite. This observation makes me wonder whether the approach you suggested works.

Comment: yes, I tried to work it out using my naive suggestion, and did not get anywhere. Sorry for the red herring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such a metric $\rho$ does exist.

Let $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be the canonical vectors in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$. Extend $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ to a Hamel basis $B$ for $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ and define an inner product as:

$$\left\langle\sum_{b \in B} \alpha_b b, \sum_{b \in B} \beta_b b\right\rangle = \sum_{b \in B} \alpha_b\beta_b$$

The sums are finite because every vector in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is a finite linear combination of vectors in $B$. The inner product defines a norm $\|x\| = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$, and the norm defines a metric $\rho(x,y) = \|x-y\|$.

Indeed, $\rho$ satisfies the desired property. Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^\infty$ be two sequences such that $x_i = y_i$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{j\}$.

If $$x = \sum_{b \in B\setminus\{e_j\}} \alpha_b b + \alpha e_j$$

then

$$y = x + (y_j - x_j)e_j = \sum_{b \in B\setminus\{e_j\}} \alpha_b b + (\alpha  + y_j - x_j) e_j$$

necessarily, because the representation as a linear combination of basis elements is unique.

Therefore, $$\rho(x, y) = \|(y_j - x_j) e_j\| = |y_j - x_j|$$

Comment: I guess the norm you have defined is not compatible with the topology of pointwise convergence (which I believe is non-metrizable)?

Comment: @ziggurism The topology of pointwise convergence (aka the product topology) is metrisable. The metric constructed in this answer defines a different topology.

Comment: @DanielFischer Right. I guess I am thinking of pointwise convergence on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @ziggurism Indeed, the sequence $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $0$ in the product topology, but does not converge with respect to $\rho$ because $\rho(e_m, e_n) = \sqrt{2}$ for all $m \ne n$.

Comment: Wow, very nice answer. Thank you!